# Whats the most effective way to swap html output

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm writing a graphics based app in html5, js & css3. At this point it takes user input and creates an array of numbers that I intend to use to generate a graphics based result.

What is the most efficient way to display the result over the existing page? This likely sounds a little vague, I'm not really sure how to phrase the question. Which obviously doesn't help when searching for an answer.

So here's the options I've considered so far.

1. place an id="here" in a high level  tag and use js to rewrite the entire contents when I want to generate the result.
2. make my html very bare bones & put all the html construction for both displays into to js functions, enabling moving from one display to the next.
3. use an iframe tag & essentially do the same, using separate html files for each display

or ????

I suspect there is an easy & elegant answer to this. Even just a good search term for it, would be great.

Cheers

Comment: Definitely sounds like you should look at templating. I use [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding of the question, you want to build some dynamic number of elements that will be displayed to the user and you want to do it in a way that keeps performance up.

I suggest you go with having bare bone html and dynamically build your dynamic display using javascript functions.

You can significantly improve performance by ensuring the container of the elements you are dynamically building has its display set to none, this will prevent the browser from redrawing elements after every element you insert.

**Edit:**

What I mean by the `display:none` comment was if you were building your display like this:

HTML:

```
<p>Your results:</p>
<div id="divResults">
</div>
```

Javascript (assuming jQuery):

```
var divResults = $('#divResults');
function BuildResults(arr) {
   divResults.children().remove();
   var i = arr.length;
   while (i--) {
      var spnResult = $('<span class="result">');
      divResults.append(spnResult);
   }
}
```

each time you call `divResults.append(spnResult);` the browser will redraw the elements on the page, which on scale could kill performance. The solution to this is hiding `divResults` before emptying/appending elements and finally showing after your results have been rebuilt.

However if you're going with the approach of building a big element in javascript and then appending that once to the page, you don't need to worry about hiding/showing the container before/after you append the results structure.

Comment: yep, you have summed up what I'm after and using js functions was my gut instinct, ta.

Comment: hmmm, I'm new to this, don't hit return when composing a reply! Can you add a little to your comment on setting the display field to none. My intent will be to draw the entire display only after all the elements are added, in effect swapping one display for the next in one hit.

Comment: :) thanks Zeb, there's enough info in there for me to google the details and I'll use this exercise to get into jquery. Very much appreciated.